# Sorting three numbers

Tags: java, sorting

```
import bwi.prog.utils.TextIO;

    public class MinMidMax {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int a,b,c;

            int greatest, mid, smallest;

            TextIO.putln("Enter three numbers");
            TextIO.put("a=");
            a = TextIO.getInt();
            TextIO.put("b=");
            b = TextIO.getInt();
            TextIO.put("c=");
            c = TextIO.getlnInt();

            greatest = Math.max(a, Math.max(b,c));
            smallest = Math.min(a, Math.min(b,c));

            if (a < greatest && a > smallest )
                mid = a;
            else if (b < greatest && b > smallest )
                mid = b;
            else
                mid = c;

            if(a<b && a<c && b<c){ // a<b<c
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","a", "b", "c");
            }
            else if(a<c && a<b && c<b){ // a<c<b
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","a", "c", "b");
            }
            else if(b<a && b<c && a<c){ // b<a<c
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","b", "a", "c");
            }
            else if(b<c && b<a && c<a){ // b<c<a
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","b", "c", "a");
            }
            else if(c<a && c<b && a<b){ // c<a<b
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","c", "a", "b");
            }
            else if (c<b && c<a && b<a){                                  //c<b<a
            TextIO.put("\n");
            TextIO.putln("ordered:");
            TextIO.putf("%d<%d<%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
            TextIO.putf("%s<%s<%s\n","c", "b", "a");
            }
            else if ( a==b && b==a && a>c && b > c){  // c<a=b
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",c, a, b);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","c", "a", "b");

            }
            else if ( a==b && b==a && a<c && b < c){   //a=b<c
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d=%d<%d\n",a, b, c);
                TextIO.putf("%s=%s<%s","a", "b", "c");    
            }
            else if ( a==c && c==a && a>b && c > b){ //b<a=c
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",b, a, c);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","b", "a", "c");    
            }
            else if ( a==c && c==a && a<b && c<b){ //a=c<b
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d=%d<%d\n",a, c, b);
                TextIO.putf("%s=%s<%s","a", "c", "b");
            }
            else if ( a<b && a<c && b==c && c==b){   //a<b=c
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",a, b, c);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","a", "b", "c");
            }
            else if ( b==c && c==b && c<a && b< a)  // b=c<a
            {
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d=%d<%d\n",b, c, a);
                TextIO.putf("%s=%s<%s","b", "c", "a");

            }

            else if (a == b && a == c && b == c && b == a && c==b && c==a)   //a=b=c
            {
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d=%d=%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s=%s=%s","a", "b", "c");
            }
            else if (a < b && a < c && b == c && c==b)   //a<b=c
            {
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","a", "b", "c");
            }
            else if (b<a && b<c && a == b && b == a)   //b<a=c
            {
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","b", "a", "c");
            }
            else if (c<a && c<b && a == b && b == a)   //c<a=b
            {
                TextIO.put("\n");
                TextIO.putln("ordered:");
                TextIO.putf("%d<%d=%d\n",smallest, mid, greatest);
                TextIO.putf("%s<%s=%s","c", "b", "a");
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will achieve the same goal in much less code.

```
import bwi.prog.utils.TextIO;
import java.util.*;

public class MinMidMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Map<Integer, Character> vars = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>();
        // get input
        TextIO.putln("Enter three numbers");  
        for (Character c = 'a'; c <= 'c'; c++) {
            TextIO.putf("%s=", c);
            vars.put(TextIO.getInt(), c);
        }
        // print the result
        StringBuilder sbValues = new StringBuilder("\nordered:\n");
        StringBuilder sbVars = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> e : vars.entrySet()) {
            sbValues.append(e.getValue());
            sbValues.append("\t<");
            sbVars.append(e.getKey());
            sbVars.append("\t<");
        }
        sbVars.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        sbValues.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        TextIO.putln(sbValues);
        TextIO.putln(sbVars);
    }
}
```

The `TreeMap` class automatically sorts its keys, and iterating through them is relatively trivial.

Not that `StringBuilder` has been used to build strings for later output, so you can remove the remaining `\t<` at the end.

The [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package can make your life much easier.

Note that this also supports an arbitrary amount of inputs, just change `c <= 'c'` to any character greater than `'c'` on the ASCII table.

Comment: I would use a `TreeMap<Integer,Character>` instead. `TreeMap` automatically keeps its keys sorted, and doesn't require an explicit `Collections.sort()`. Also, using `Character` avoids the `""+c` hack.

Comment: You also don't need `items` — you can just get it from `vars.keySet()`, which is guaranteed to be a `SortedSet` if `vars` is a `TreeMap`.

Comment: The `Map` doesn't handle duplicate values well at all, though!

Comment: @200_success Modified to address first two comments. Changed to `TreeMap<Integer, Character>` and used resulting `entrySet()` with `StringBuilder`.